# SQL Server database connection fails

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

My asp.net website cannot connect to my SQL Server database, it shows this error message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

My connection string is:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=admin_;Integrated Security=False;User ID=*****;Password=****;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096
```

Comment: Did you try debugging to find where is the issue?

Comment: Is it only saying internal server error? No exception message? If you will open it in IIS locally, the YPOD would show the stack trace

Comment: yes this is the only error

Comment: at first I though the brobleme is in the serveur and I contact the owner to solve it. but he tolds me the problem is in the syntax of your string connection, so I tried many syntaxes without a result

Comment: You need to show us the actual error, no one can help you with this as you have provided no information